# Is there a way in XML to define a common piece of document to be customized later in other documents?

Tags: xml

Let's make a simple example to explain my question.

Let's say I want to have an XML file called `shopping-bag.xml` which defines `<Rice>`, `<Spaghetti>`, `<Milk>`, ... 
That file will be my "abstract data".
Then, in other XML files the abstract data will be "included" and customized with actual data, by passing to that the actual quantities to buy; that will replace the default values with my actual value for the specific implementation.

Is there any way to implement and use such "common & abstract data" in XML?

---

Adding details, inspired by comments.

what I would like to achieve is the ability to customize common data within other XML files, outside any actual application.

In reality, I would like to offer users to "include" the common-data XML file in their own files and then customize the common data within their file. Let's think like inheriting the common data to make a customized version of that in another XML.

Users should be able to define their own XML files by customizing the common-data XML, something like this:

I have two files:

- `common-data.xml`
- `user-customized.xml`

and the `user-customized.xml` file includes the first file to use that as common data to be customized with specific parameters, something as:

```
#include common-data.xml <parameters to customize the common data>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just read `shopping-bag.xml`, update the relevant nodes with actual data and save (or save to a new file)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, what I would like to achieve is the ability to customize common data within other XML files, outside the application. In reality, I would like to offer users to "include" the common-data XML file in their own files and then customize the common data within their file. Let's think like inheriting the common data to make a customized version of that in another XML.